# Removing element and relinking custom linked list (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a small program where we create a custom linked list that can take in objects derived from the Shape class. The linked list is built up by nodes that contains a link to the next node and a shape-object.

The header for the custom linked list class (ShapeList) is following:

```
class ShapeList {
public:

    ShapeList() : listStart(0) {
    }
    ShapeList(const ShapeList &shapes);

    ~ShapeList() {
        if (listStart != 0) delete listStart;
    }
    void add(const Shape& s);
    void remove(const Vertex& v);
    double area();
    void print();

private:
    Node * listStart;
};
```

The header for the Nodes:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node(const Shape *v, Node * next): nextNode(next) {shapeInst = v->clone();}
//    Node (const Node &nod);
    ~Node() {if (shapeInst != 0) delete shapeInst;}
     Shape * getShape()  {return shapeInst;}
     Node * getNextNode()  {return nextNode;}
        void operator=(const Node * node){
        shapeInst = node->shapeInst->clone();
        nextNode = node->nextNode;
    }

private:
    Shape * shapeInst;
    Node * nextNode;
};
```

The problem arrives when I try to remove elements from the linked list. It seems that I successfully remove the objects, but that the list doesn't re-link after removal.

I have tried to implement the following code for the remove-function:

```
void ShapeList::remove(const Vertex& v) {

    Node * prev;

    Node* tmp = listStart;
    double x, y;

    if (listStart == NULL) {
        cout << "No objects present in the list!" << endl;
    } else {
        while (tmp != NULL) {

            x = tmp->getShape()->getX() - v.getXposition();
            y = tmp->getShape()->getY() - v.getYposition();

            if (x < 1 && y < 1) {

                if (tmp == listStart) {
                    listStart = tmp->getNextNode();
                    delete tmp;
                } else {
                    Node * next = tmp->getNextNode();
                    delete tmp;
                }

            } else {
                prev = tmp;
                tmp = tmp->getNextNode();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which crashes when I try to iterate trough the list after removal.

When I change **Node * next = tmp->getNextNode();** to **prev->getNextNode() = tmp->getNextNode();** (As shown in the delete-function in http://www.cprogramming.com/snippets/source-code/singly-linked-list-insert-remove-add-count)

The code returns following error

```
ShapeList.cpp:69:41: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
                     prev->getNextNode() = tmp->getNextNode();
                                         ^
```

Am I missing something important here or am I just staring myself blind on my own code?

Comment: This is a classic linked list problem. You can likely find this with a little googling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting Node in Linked List C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603009/deleting-node-in-linked-list-c)

Comment: Thats a pretty clear error message, youre trying to assign into a temporary (which doesnt make a whole lot of sense).

Comment: @Borgleader I see. I did som pretty extensive googling on the lvalue required as left operand of assignment -error but it seemed as the majority of the results were people mixing up = and == with a little dose of people missunderstanding arithmetic sequencing, but I'll try to look harder!

Comment: @erip Thanks, I'll look trough the linked post and check if It'll get me closer to the answer!

Comment: This is another reason to have the node members public.  If the were public you could just use `prev->nextNode = temp->nextNode`

Comment: @NathanOliver even with nodemembers public I get  ShapeList.cpp:69:42: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
                     prev->getNextNode()  = tmp->getNextNode();

Comment: @Tjernquist1 Yes because `prev->getNextNode()` is a temporary.  If you want to have the member private then you need to make the function return a reference to the pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah, I see my mistake now. Unfortunately all node members must be kept private unless specificly stated in the assignment, so it seems that I cant make the node members public

Comment: A simple solution would be to add `void Node::setNextNode(Node*)` and a similar setter `void Node::setShapeInst(Shape*)`.

Comment: Also, your `void Node::operator(const Node*)` is defined incorrectly; a more correct version needs to a) check if `this != other` and b) return a reference to itself to allow for operator chaining.

Comment: Amazing, @iksemyonov I got it to work now. Silly me, comming from Java I should have known to utilize setters and not only getters. Thanks!

Comment: you welcome, and coming from Java, remember to pay attention to pointers vs references vs values!